# Can't import librosa-module into python

Tags: python, import, module, path, librosa

Windows 10 machine + fresh install of Python 3.7 (Microsoft store) and python-extension in VSCode. The interpreter is set to the default installation location of python after an install using the MS-store and the current folder is set to be interpreted.

```
pip install librosa
```

in powershell yields

```
Collecting librosa
  Using cached librosa-0.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (203 kB)
Collecting pooch>=1.0
  Using cached pooch-1.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (51 kB)
Collecting scipy>=1.0.0
  Using cached scipy-1.7.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (33.6 MB)
Collecting audioread>=2.0.0
  Using cached audioread-2.1.9.tar.gz (377 kB)
Collecting joblib>=0.14
  Using cached joblib-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (303 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.15.0
  Using cached numpy-1.21.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (13.9 MB)
Collecting resampy>=0.2.2
  Using cached resampy-0.2.2.tar.gz (323 kB)
Collecting soundfile>=0.10.2
  Using cached SoundFile-0.10.3.post1-py2.py3.cp26.cp27.cp32.cp33.cp34.cp35.cp36.pp27.pp32.pp33-none-win_amd64.whl (689 kB)
Collecting scikit-learn!=0.19.0,>=0.14.0
  Using cached scikit_learn-0.24.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (6.8 MB)
Collecting numba>=0.43.0
  Using cached numba-0.53.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (2.3 MB)
Collecting packaging>=20.0
  Using cached packaging-21.0-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting decorator>=3.0.0
  Using cached decorator-5.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (8.9 kB)
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting appdirs
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Collecting six>=1.3
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting cffi>=1.0
  Using cached cffi-1.14.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (178 kB)
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0
  Using cached threadpoolctl-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting llvmlite<0.37,>=0.36.0rc1
  Using cached llvmlite-0.36.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (16.0 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\windowsapps\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages (from numba>=0.43.0->librosa) (47.1.0)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.0.2
  Using cached pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
Collecting chardet<5,>=3.0.2
  Using cached chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting pycparser
  Using cached pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
Using legacy setup.py install for audioread, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy setup.py install for resampy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyparsing, packaging, certifi, chardet, idna, urllib3, requests, appdirs, pooch, numpy, scipy, audioread, joblib, llvmlite, numba, six, resampy, pycparser, cffi, soundfile, threadpoolctl, scikit-learn, decorator, librosa
    Running setup.py install for audioread ... done
    Running setup.py install for resampy ... done
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.4 audioread-2.1.9 certifi-2021.5.30 cffi-1.14.5 chardet-4.0.0 decorator-5.0.9 idna-2.10 joblib-1.0.1 librosa-0.8.1 llvmlite-0.36.0 numba-0.53.1 numpy-1.21.0 packaging-21.0 pooch-1.4.0 pycparser-2.20 pyparsing-2.4.7 requests-2.25.1 
resampy-0.2.2 scikit-learn-0.24.2 scipy-1.7.0 six-1.16.0 soundfile-0.10.3.post1 threadpoolctl-2.1.0 urllib3-1.26.6
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 21.1.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

(download is skipped because of earlier tests)

```
pip list
```

yields

```
Package       Version
------------- ------------
appdirs       1.4.4
audioread     2.1.9
certifi       2021.5.30
cffi          1.14.5
chardet       4.0.0
decorator     5.0.9
idna          2.10
joblib        1.0.1
librosa       0.8.1
llvmlite      0.36.0
numba         0.53.1
numpy         1.21.0
packaging     21.0
pooch         1.4.0
pycparser     2.20
pyparsing     2.4.7
requests      2.25.1
resampy       0.2.2
scikit-learn  0.24.2
scipy         1.7.0
six           1.16.0
SoundFile     0.10.3.post1
threadpoolctl 2.1.0
urllib3       1.26.6
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 21.1.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

So it's definetely there. Opening an empty .py-file and writing + starting

```
import librosa
```

yields

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/j/Desktop/python/noisepp.py", line 2, in <module>
    import librosa
  File "C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\librosa\__init__.py", line 211, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\librosa\core\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .convert import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\librosa\core\convert.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import notation
  File "C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\librosa\core\notation.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..util.exceptions import ParameterError
  File "C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\librosa\util\__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .utils import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\librosa\util\utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    import scipy.ndimage
  File "C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py", line 61, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 
364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I tried adding

```
C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts
```

to PATH variable, since VSCode had a pop-up which told me to do so. No effect. What could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

install scipy. I was getting error in import numba, import librosa. installled scipy and its ok now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).